# Finding second largest in table department wise

Tags: mysql

I have a table names 'emp'. Columns are:
uid,emp_name,emp_dept,emp_sal.

Now i want to find second largest salary of employee in each department.
Please suggest me query.
I have used this query, but it doesn't show me desired result::

```
 select max(emp_sal) from emp where emp_sal<(select max(emp_sal) from emp)
 group by emp_dept
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you are using MySql, you can take advantage of the `offset` parameter in the limit clause.

```
SELECT e.emp_dept, 
    ( SELECT p.emp_sal
      FROM emp p 
      WHERE p.emp_dept = e.emp_dept 
      ORDER BY p.emp_sal DESC 
      LIMIT 1,1) secondHighestSal
FROM emp e
GROUP BY e.emp_dept
```

Answer (score 0):

SELECT SAL FROM EMP WHERE SAL IN (SELECT MAX(SAL) FROM EMP WHERE SAL <> (SELECT MAX(SAL) FROM EMP))

Answer (score 0):

By using the bellow query we will be get the second highest value of the all the department with out using LIMIT

```
SELECT a . * FROM emp AS a 
WHERE 2 = (SELECT count( a.uid )
FROM emp AS b 
WHERE a.emp_sal <= b.emp_sal AND a.emp_dept = b.emp_dept 
GROUP BY a.emp_dept )
```